# Numpy.cov() in Python returning a matrix of NaN's instead of 0's

Tags: classification, python, covariance, numpy

The cov() method from the numpy library returns a covariance matrix where columns represent different features and rows represent separate instances of the same feature. Therefore, passing a nx1 column vector to the cov() method should return a nxn covariance matrix of 0's. Instead the function is returning a nxn matrix of NaN's.
The covariance of a set A, {x}, with itself is 0, and the covariance of any two single element sets will similarly be a product of 0's.
One possibility is that the cov function is using the bessel correction for sample covariance which would produce a denominator of 0. I am actually looking at samples in order to classify data. For class

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cov.html) (since I'm not a python user), I see

```
bias: bool, optional
Default normalization (False) is by (N - 1), where N is the number of 
observations given (unbiased estimate). If bias is True, then 
normalization is by N. These values can be overridden by using the keyword 
ddof in numpy versions >= 1.5.
```

so it looks as though the default is to divide by $N-1$, which would give `NaN`, as is pretty much universal in statistical software, but there's an option to divide by $N$.